# How to read a UDT from a postgres stored function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc, user-defined-types

I can't seem to read a UDT properly from a stored function with the
postgres JDBC driver. This is some sample code:

```
CREATE TYPE u_country AS ENUM ('Brazil', 'England', 'Germany')

CREATE TYPE u_street_type AS (
  street VARCHAR(100),
  no VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TYPE u_address_type AS (
  street u_street_type,
  zip VARCHAR(50),
  city VARCHAR(50),
  country u_country,
  since DATE,
  code INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE t_author (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth DATE,
  year_of_birth INTEGER,
  address u_address_type
)

INSERT INTO t_author VALUES (1, 'George', 'Orwell',
TO_DATE('1903-06-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1903, ROW(ROW('Parliament Hill',
'77'), 'NW31A9', 'Hampstead', 'England', '1980-01-01', null))
INSERT INTO t_author VALUES (2, 'Paulo', 'Coelho',
TO_DATE('1947-08-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1947, ROW(ROW('Caixa Postal',
'43.003'), null, 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Brazil', '1940-01-01', 2))

CREATE FUNCTION p_enhance_address2 (address OUT u_address_type)
AS $$
BEGIN
        SELECT t_author.address
        INTO address
        FROM t_author
        WHERE first_name = 'George';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now the above works perfectly in postgres. I can also select the UDT
column t_author.address with a SQL SELECT statement directly. But when
I select from the stored function p_enhance_address2 via JDBC, I get a
weird behaviour. I tried these two invocation schemes:

```
connection.prepareStatement("select * from p_enhance_address2()");
connection.prepareCall("{ call p_enhance_address2(?) }"); 
// the latter with an output parameter registered
```

Both calling schemes induce the same behaviour (actually the
CallableStatement is nothing else than selecting from the function).
There seem to be two very distinct problems:

The nested UDT structure completely screws up fetching results. This
is what I get with JDBC:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
  "select * from p_enhance_address2()");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("# of columns: " + 
    rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount());
  System.out.println(rs.getObject(1));
}
```

Output:

> nr of columns: 6 
>   ("(""Parliament Hill"",77)",NW31A9)

Why are there 6 columns? And why is the UDT incorrectly fetched (many
fields are missing)

A little improvement can be achieved, when the nested UDT
u_street_type is "flattened" to a varchar, which leads to the
assumption that nested UDT's are poorly supported by the JDBC driver:

```
CREATE TYPE u_address_type AS (
  street VARCHAR(80),
  zip VARCHAR(50),
  city VARCHAR(50),
  country u_country,
  since DATE,
  code INTEGER
)

INSERT INTO t_author VALUES (1, 'George', 'Orwell',
TO_DATE('1903-06-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1903, ROW('Parliament Hill 77',
'NW31A9', 'Hampstead', 'England', '1980-01-01', null))
INSERT INTO t_author VALUES (2, 'Paulo', 'Coelho',
TO_DATE('1947-08-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1947, ROW('Caixa Postal 43.003',
null, 'Rio de Janeiro', 'Brazil', '1940-01-01', 2))
```

Then the results will be something like this:

> nr of columns: 6
>   ("Parliament Hill 77",NW31A9,Hampstead,England,1980-01-01,)

The UDT record now looks correct (fetched from the result set at
position 1). But there are still 6 columns in the result set.

Some facts:

- I do not experience these problems in pgAdmin III
- I use PostgreSQL 9.0.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 64-bit
- I use postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar

**Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?**

Comment: In python, I always have to custom map a type when trying to nest rows. - or just not do it :-(

Comment: Yes, probably it's a lot easier not to do these things, because their support is not good in many RDBMS or JDBC drivers (or python - I don't know about that). That's why I'm trying to "standardise" access to advanced, vendor-specific SQL features through my database interfacing library jOOQ: http://jooq.sourceforge.net. And in jOOQ, I want to be able to use nested UDT's because I expect my users to use that functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this and it seems that this is a bug.

I would suggest you post this to the PostgreSQL JDBC mailing list, so the developers can fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't sure about this being a bug or me incorrectly doing something...

Comment: Starts looking like a bug on the user group... http://groups.google.com/group/pgsql.interfaces.jdbc/browse_thread/thread/58568fd0699b246f/142aa7fec27cac44

Answer (score 2):

If am not wrong UDT (user defined type) not officially supported (JDBC conformance) by postgres9.4 drivers (postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar). I also face lot of problem while calling postgres function form java code.
I used below drivers and solved my problem.

here is the non official driver link,
http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/
copy driver form the link create connection as explained in below

please see below working example from my POC Oracle10g to Postgres9.4 migration activity see below example POC,

```
-- Function: fn_test_t(text)

-- DROP FUNCTION fn_test_t(text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test_t(
    IN txt text,
    OUT a typ_address[],
    OUT b typ_address[])
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
address typ_address[];
BEGIN
RAISE INFO '@@ inside fn_test:(%)',111;
address[1] := ROW('Amravati', 'Mahalaxmi', ROW('Test1'));
address[2] := ROW('Pune', 'NICMAR',ROW('Test2'));
address[3] := ROW('', '',ROW('Test3'));
RAISE INFO 'array of address:(%)',address;
--a := ROW(address); 
--b := ROW(address); 
a := address; 
b := address; 
RAISE INFO 'typ_address_t a:(%)',a;
RAISE INFO 'typ_address_t b:(%)',b;
  --  RETURN address;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION fn_test_t(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;

=========================
-- Type: typ_address

-- DROP TYPE typ_address;

CREATE TYPE typ_address AS
   (add1 character varying,
    add2 character varying,
    t typ_test);
ALTER TYPE typ_address
  OWNER TO postgres;
==========================
-- Type: typ_test

-- DROP TYPE typ_test;

CREATE TYPE typ_test AS
   (t1 character varying);
ALTER TYPE typ_test
  OWNER TO postgres;
==========================
```

Main function call,

```
public static void oracleToPosgresUDTCall() {
        System.out.println("@@@ inside oracleToPosgresUDTCall...");
          Connection c = null;
          try {
             Class.forName("com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver");
             c = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:pgsql://localhost:5433/orapg", "postgres", "root");
             System.out.println(c.getMetaData().getDriverVersion());

             //you can map your UDT to pojo here Great !!!
             Map<String, Class<?>> m = c.getTypeMap();
             m.put("typ_address", Address.class);
             m.put("typ_test", AddressTypeTest.class);
             c.setTypeMap(m);

             // Procedure call
             CallableStatement cstmt = c.prepareCall("{call fn_test_t(?,?,?)}");

             cstmt.setString(1, "791000252423");

             cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY);
             cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY);


                boolean b = cstmt.execute();

             Array arr = cstmt.getArray(1); //output array starts from index 1

             System.out.println("arr:" + arr.getBaseTypeName());
             Object obj = arr.getArray();

             System.out.println("Address obj:" + obj);
             Address[] a = (Address[])obj;
             System.out.println("Address obj:" + a[0].getAdd1());
             System.out.println("Address obj:" + a[0].getTypeTest().getT1());

             System.out.println("=======================================================");
             //MORE

             List<Address> list = Arrays.asList(a);

             for(Address aa: list){
                 System.out.println(aa.getAdd1());
                 System.out.println(aa.getAdd2());
                 System.out.println("t1:" + aa.getTypeTest().getT1());
             }



             cstmt.close();

          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
          }
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
       }
```